# Incorrect Start time and End time of an Incoming meeting in a Calendar list in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar, incoming-email

I have a calendar list on sharepoint 2016 for managing meetings in our organization. The problem is when we send a meeting by outlook to this list the Start and End Time field has about 14 hours difference with the actual start time however the Created time field is correct. we all checked the time zone of server,sharepoint regional setting,outlook and all of them are the same. 
The point is that incoming meeting that send from gmail is set on a correct time in this list.
Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?